# What's the first number that JavaScript can't represent accurately?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with currency values, so it's important to calculate accurately.

My current code breaks down a string into tokens then evaluates them. For decimal values, it first converts them to integers, does the calculation then converts back to a decimal.

For example if I had the expression

```
"0.1 * 0.2"
```

The first step would be to break it down into the tokens `0.1`, `*` and `0.2`. It then does some other malarky and figures it needs to multiple `0.1` and `0.2` together. The calculation would be

```
1 * 2 / 100
```

The calculation is done as integers to prevent JavaScript rounding error, i.e.

```
0.1 * 0.2 == 0.020000000000000004
```

My colleges argument is that by converting to a float from a string initially you've already lost precision. So my question is **what's the upper bound and lower bound either side of 0 where a number cannot be represented by JavaScript exactly?** So that I can check for this and handle it, if that's the right approach.

Comment: The right approach is to use decimals instead. There are few implementations in JavaScript. For example have a look at this: https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you describe isn't a bounds problem. IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point numbers can represent the value `0.5` perfectly, but cannot represent, say, `0.1` perfectly. Note that those have the same number of digits. The issue isn't the number of places of precision, it's the fact that the number type uses a different number base than we do. It uses base 2, rather than our base 10.

Just as we can't accurately represent `1 / 3` in our base 10 system, certain numbers cannot be accurately represented in IEEE-754's base 2 system.

In 2008, the IEEE came out with a revision adding a *new* format to IEEE-754 (it defines several formats; the "double-precision binary" one used by JS is just one of them) called "[decimal64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format)" which uses base 10 rather than base 2, for applications that need to handle rounding the same way we do (financial apps and such). That may start seeping into programming languages and such; for now, IEEE-754 single-precision and double-precision are the typical ones used, and others not based on the recent IEEE-754 standard like C#'s `decimal`.

In the meantime, there are "big decimal" libraries for JavaScript, such as [big.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/) (haven't used it, no affiliation). If you search for "bignumber in JavaScript" or "JavaScript exact floating point" you should find multiple options.

Comment: I understand the different bases used, I confuse my self every time I revisit this topic though. I guess is there a number you could write as a decimal (string) that you couldn't convert to a JavaScript float. For example `0.55555555555555555` becomes `0.5555555555555556` but what are the bounds/limits on this?

Comment: Or is there some obscure number like `0.234` that would become `0.235`, as it can't be represented correctly.

Comment: @Ally: I don't think the bounds can be reasonably expressed in our decimal system (but I'm not an expert in the arcana of floating point systems). Again, it's not a matter of decimal places, as the typical `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004` example can attest.

Comment: @Ally I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with these bounds/limits? You already know that `0.1 * 0.2 == 0.020000000000000004`. If you do lots of such small operations you may end up with totally wrong amount (and there is no way to handle it using floats only). And if you are dealing with money then you are screwed beyond help. Use decimals instead.

Comment: @freakish I think I'm trying to establish if there's anything I can check to know that doing the equation in JavaScript is safe before resorting to a JavaScript library to handle it. I assume that [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) library always uses strings and never converts to floats, which I imagine is slow, so if I can avoid doing it for all cases that would make things faster.

Comment: @Ally What is more important: performance or correctness? Obviously every decimal implementation will be slower then floats. However does it really matter? I mean waiting 0.2ms instead of 0.1ms (random numbers, I'm just trying to show the scale of the problem) is not a big deal - noone will notice. However if you are doing some heavy arithemtic operations then you should not use JavaScript in the first place. Also loading 2kb script is not a big deal nowadays as well.

Comment: @Ally: Sadly, I don't think you can. I mean, there are certain things you can do: The result of an addition or subtraction will never have more digits after the decimal than its operands (e.g., `1.24 + 4` will never have more than two decimal places), so if you're doing addition/subtraction, you could do it and then look at the result's places-after-the-decimal, as these things usually (always???) result in values with large numbers of places to the right of the decimal. I don't *think* that rule is true for multiplication, but I'm not a maths whiz. Obviously it isn't true for division. :-)

Comment: Why do you think it can represent `0.2` exactly? It can `0.5`, but `0.2` should be just as in inexact as `0.1`

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks, please feel free to correct as you see fit. As I've said, I'm not an expert in the implementation details, I'm just familiar with the concepts. ***Edit***: Actually, your comment had enough info in it for *me* to fix that part of the answer. Now I say it can accurately contain 0.5, but not 0.2. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think that's the same argument you've used: because 0.5 == 1/2 which can be represented as finite number in base 2, while 0.2 is 1/5.

Comment: @freakish: Thanks. Dead simple, when you put it like that. :-)

Comment: @freakish It does matter, the app requires lots of math calculations. Given the choice I probably wouldn't of chosen JS to do this either, I don't think this will be so uncommon in the future though with Node.js and now Win.js existing. Correctness comes first so will have to use that, just exploring the possibility of speeding it up a bit. Thanks for your help anyway.

T.J.Crowder: Thanks, if it's not possible it's not possible. I think I'll handle all calculations with a Decimal library, even though it's slower.

Comment: @Ally: Yeah, if you have to, you have to. FWIW, for me (e.g, my midrange hardware), even on IE8 in a virtual machine, Big.js can manage to do ~1k ops/second (http://jsbin.com/hitugemo/1), IE10 can do >10k/second, and Chrome or Firefox are in the 30-50k/second range. Of course, that's **dramatically** slower compared to native numbers (http://jsbin.com/hitugemo/2 -- which is why we use things like IEEE-754 in the first place!), but still...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, thanks for putting those tests together. That's very handy to know.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that there is any such number which you can say that it is the first number that JavaScript can't represent accurately. It is all about decimal numbers and loss of precision.

Also to add there is no decimal data type in JavaScript - the only numeric data type is floating-point. JavaScript uses 64-bit floating point representation.

Floating point rounding errors. 0.1 cannot be represented as accurately in base-2 as in base-10 due to the missing prime factor of 5. Also to note that every floating point math is like this and is based on the [IEEE 754 standard.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats)

Comment: Whoops, I guess I need to rephrase that, I meant what's the first number with the least amount of decimals JavaScript can't handle? Maybe

Comment: @Ally: There isn't one. It's not an issue with the number of decimal places. It's an issue with the way IEEE-754 double-precision floating point works (it doesn't use the same number base we do).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:- Yes very correct. I also updated that with my answer!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, all JS engines uses IEEE 754 double to handle floating point numbers.

Take a look at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format page, section 'Double-precision examples'. In the case numbers are close to 0, take a closer look at subnormals formula:

[image: $$(-1)^{\text{sign}} \times 2^{1 - \text{exponent bias}} \times 0.\text{mantissa}$$]

So, the closest to zero number, that can be represented in JavaScript floating point datatype is 2<sup>1-1023</sup> * 2<sup>-52</sup> = 2<sup>-1022</sup> * 2<sup>-52</sup> = 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

Empirically:

```
Math.pow(2,-1074) = 5e-324
Math.pow(2,-1075) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know.

Comment: added actual closest to zero number: +/- 2^(-1074)

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are doing currency calculations. You may find it better to use integers here. Use an integer to represent the price in cents. This eliminates problems with floating point which are more suitable for scientific calculations. This would basically be equivalent to using a BigDecimal in java.

Comment: Javascript only has a single number type. It cannot represent integers out-of-the-box.